# VBA - Is there something similar to lists?

Tags: vba, excel

For instance, I have a list of two numbers 0, 1 and I want to run a script in vba which goes like this:

```
for i in list:
    if i in string:
       do something
    end if
```

i.e. I want to first check if "0" is in some string, then do something, and then check if "1" is in the string then do something etc. In python I would have a tuple ["0","1"] and do it like that, but how would I go about this in VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this? You can use an array (which I suppose is *technically* a tuple when no data type is defined)

```
For Each i In Array("0", "1", "2", "3")
    If InStr("1289", i) Then
        '// Do Something
    End If
Next
```

Similarly:

```
Dim list As Variant
Dim someString As String

someString = "1289"
list = Array("0", "1", "2", "3")

For Each i In list
    If InStr(someString, i) Then
        '// Do Something
    End If
Next
```

---

Bonus notes:

`InStr()` doesn't actually return `True/False` it returns the start position of a substring inside another string reading from left to right. In this case however, we can rely on VBA's implicit conversion to evaluate anything greater than `0` as `True` because it's being used in an `If` statement.

Comment: Just an extra question, if I wanted to call say, the third item in an array - how would I do that?

Comment: Assuming you have assigned the array to a variable: `MsgBox list(2)` (arrays are zero-based by default in VBA, so 2 is actually the third item)